# Two columns use full width, the first is a resizable textarea

Tags: html, css

I want to do an editor, with code on left, result on right.

**Why is the `<div>` #right's text sticked to the white/blue boundary? Why isn't there any padding? (I would like a 10 px padding).**

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0; }
html, body { height: 100%; overflow: hidden; }
.column { padding: 10px; overflow: y-scroll; height: calc(100% - 20px); }
#writing { min-width: 1px; max-width: 99%; float: left;  width: 50%; resize: horizontal;  }
#right { background-color: blue; }
```

```html
<textarea id="writing" class="column">you can drag the width of this column with bottom right corner: resize </textarea>
<div id="right" class="column">
Why is this sticked to the white/blue boundary ? why no padding? I want a 10 px padding!
```

Answer (score 1):

`#right` is spread under the floating `textarea` and your text stands far the padding, it is pushed by the floatting `textarea`.

You can reset the [block formating context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context) of the non floatting element. with overflow for example

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0; }
html, body { height: 100%; overflow: hidden; }
.column { padding: 10px; overflow: y-scroll; height: calc(100% - 20px); }
#writing { min-width: 1px; max-width: 99%; float: left;  width: 50%; resize: horizontal;  }
#right { background-color: blue;overflow:hidden; }
```

```html
<textarea id="writing" class="column">you can drag the width of this column with bottom right corner: resize </textarea>
<div id="right" class="column">
Why is this sticked to the white/blue boundary ? why no padding? I want a 10 px padding!
```

---

**Set a transparent background to your code and add overflow on hover to see what it does:**

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0; }
html, body { height: 100%; overflow: hidden; }
.column { padding: 10px; overflow: y-scroll; height: calc(100% - 20px); }
#writing { min-width: 1px; max-width: 99%; float: left;  width: 50%; resize: horizontal;background:transparent;  }
#right { background-color: blue;border:solid; }
#right:hover {overflow:hidden;}
```

```html
<textarea id="writing" class="column">you can drag the width of this column with bottom right corner: resize </textarea>
<div id="right" class="column"><b>HOVER ME</b>
Why is this sticked to the white/blue boundary ? why no padding? I want a 10 px padding!
```

Answer (score 1):

If you correct

```
overflow: y-scroll;
```

to

```
overflow-y: scroll;
```

you will find that the `padding` declaration works as it ought to.

Comment: @Basj because of https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context :)

Comment: The syntax error causes the CSS parser to ignore the entire block.

Comment: Rounin: is the syntax error in my code or in this answer's code ?